# Open Woocommerce Cart Tab from menu

Tags: plugins, woocommerce, cart

I use WooCommerce Cart Tab plugin. It is possible to open the side tab directly from my menu? Like this plugin:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by side tab ?

Comment: Hi, i mean this part https://ps.w.org/woocommerce-cart-tab/assets/screenshot-1.png?rev=1591319   i can open it by clicking on that cart icon. But I would like to open it from my menu

Comment: Javascript show based on clicking the menu item.

Comment: How i can do that? This is the first time I try to make a website...